# How to minimize the elevated console window?

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

```
@echo off
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin

    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload

    echo %~nx0: running payload with parameters:
    echo %*
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    echo ADM is launching. DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW.
    cd /d %2
    shift
    shift
    sample.bat
goto :eof

exit
```

I am calling Sample.bat using the payload, i want to minimize the window when the call to sample.bat is given.

Comment: Does `start /min` work?

Comment: No it works if we are calling the batch file using start command. But in my case i am calling it through payload

Comment: Anyway, what is your aim ? I'm asking because you could throw away this script and launch an elevated app. directly from Inno Setup. Also minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
                                                                ↑
                                                              vShow
```

you used the [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of the [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object which uses the fifth parameter (`vShow`) to give a recommendation as to how the application window should be displayed initially. You have used for that parameter value 1, which is described as (equals to [`SW_SHOWNORMAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SW_SHOWNORMAL)):

> Open the application with a normal window. If the window is minimized
>   or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and
>   position.

So as first I would try to change the value of the `vShow` parameter to 7, which is described as (equals to [`SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE)):

> Open the application with a minimized window. The active window remains active.

Which for your script means to replace the above line with this:

```
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 7 >> "%vbs%"
```

Do note, that I haven't tested this.

Comment: The idea behind is to directly open the elevated window minimized. I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks TLama , the solution worked for me. It opens a elevated window in maximized window less than a fraction of second. Then minimizes it till there is any operation in batch file.

Comment: You're welcome! But, if you describe your overall aim, we can try to tune this up. What you are doing in your script can be replaced by native code in Inno Setup (it has the `ShellExec` function which does the same as `Shell.ShellExecute` method in your script).

Comment: The inno setup which i have configured, does the packaging and deploy all the batch files in C:ProgramFiles , i have created icons for the batch files on desktop, which does some operations. Thats the reason i dont want it to be configured in inno setup. Hope my requirement is clear